# Show that all triangulations of a compact surface are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm having trouble with solving the following question:

Let $T_1, T_2$ be two finite triangulations of a compact surface. Show that if $E_{T_1}\cap E_{T_2}$ is a finite set of points, where $E_{T_i}$ is the set of edges of $T_i$, then one can get from $T_1$ to $T_2$ by a finite sequence of moves of type (and their inverses):

- Dividing an edge by inserting a vertex.
- Dividing a polygon by inserting an edge and the corresponding vertices.
- Adding a vertex in the interior of a polygon and the corresponding connecting edge.

My general idea is to take two arbitrary triangulations and express them with the corresponding simplicial complexes. It seems plausible that you can somehow embed one simplicial complex into the other, such that one of the complexes will be a subdivision of the other. In such a case, I could simply remove vertices and edges from the more refined simplicial complex, until I end up with the other complex (I.E - get from one to the other in a finite sequence of the permitted steps).

My main two problems are:

- I'm not entirely sure that you can always perform the embedding I suggested.
- Even if you can, I'm not entirely sure how to describe the process in a precise way. How can I show that one complex can be embedded into the other and then transformed into the other?

Any hint would be of great help. If you could refer me to relevant reading materials, that would also be very helpful (if I'm way off and there's possibly a simpler way than what I've suggested- I'd be happy to hear).

Thank you.

Comment: $E_{T_1}\cap E_{T_2}$ is the set of common edges in $T_1, T_2$ which is always finite. Do you mean the set of all points common to an edge of $T_1$ and an edge of $T_2$?

Comment: Yes, I mean E_{T_i} as the set of points on the edge, so the intersection is the set of points common to both edges.

Comment: So you mean the intersection of the $1$-skeleta of the polyhedra detemined by $T_1, T_2$.

Comment: Yes,  that's right

Comment: You can define something called refinement of triangulation. The idea is do both the triangulations simultaneously. So this gives you a polygonalization of your surface. Each polygon you can triangulate. So you get a triangulation finer than both the initial triangulations. Now each is equivalent to the finer triangulation clearly so they are equivalent to each other.

Comment: So basically, you say that it's sufficient to show that both triangulations can be refined into the same triangulation using the steps described above. How do I find this triangulation?

Comment: @GSofer refinements are standard. What text are you using to study? I would be surprised to see something like this not mentioned.

Comment: I'm using mostly Massey's "algebraic topology - an introduction". Can you recommend a good source to read about refinements? I was thinking about suggesting the union of the two sets of vertices and edges as a possible common refinement, but I'm not entirely sure on how to show that it is indeed a proper triangulation that I can get to using the permitted steps.

Comment: As stated, the stament seems wrong: Each of the allowed steps seems to refine the triangulation, hence $T_2$ would need to be a refinement (and in particular, contain all edges of $T_1$ completely). On the other hand, the point-set union of $T_1$ and $T_2$ seems to be a good starting point for a common refinement.